# rimraf. recursively remove files and folders except specific folder

Tags: node.js, glob

```
├───app
│   ├───modules
│   │   ├───asd
│   │   │   ├───angular
│   │   │   │   ├───src
│   │   │   │   └───test
│   │   │   ├───app
│   │   │   │   └───src
│   │   │   ├───base
│   │   │   │   └───src
│   │   │   │       └───client
│   │   │   ├───common
│   │   │   │   ├───json
│   │   │   │   │   ├───src
│   │   │   │   │   └───test
│   │   │   │   ├───src
│   │   │   │   └───test
│   │   │   └───test
│   │   ├───core
│   │   │   ├───base
│   │   │   │   ├───docs
│   │   │   │   └───src
│   │   │   ├───ui
│   │   │   │   ├───directives
│   │   │   │   │   └───src
│   │   │   │   │       └───bmbDropdownMenu
│   │   │   │   │           └───css
│   │   │   │   ├───directives.CategorizedList
│   │   │   │   │   └───docs
│   │   │   │   ├───directives.noResults
│   │   │   │   │   └───lang
│   │   │   │   └───directives.popover
│   │   │   │       └───docs
```

Is it possible to remove all files and directories inside "app/modules" exception folder "core" via `rimraf` or another module?
I'm trying like this (doesn't work):

```
rimraf('./app/modules/(!(core)|**)/*.*', callback);
```

Comment: Could you use globby to specify which files you'd like to work with?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/globby

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time on this, only to figure out that `rimraf` doesn't support globbing.

I went with `del` instead, which supports the same format as `gulp` (an array of paths, including negated ones).

Answer (score -1):

```
var globby = require('globby');
var rimraf = require('rimraf');

globby(['*', '!app/modules/core.js'])
  .then(function then(paths) {
    paths.map(function map(item) {
      rimraf.sync(item);
    });
  });
```

For more info, see the [`globby` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/globby)

Credit: [vladimir-starkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057730/vladimir-starkov)

Comment: Not exactly. If I right understood, it doesn't work in depth, e.g. i can't write: globby(['**/*.*', '!dist/app/**/*.*']) -> finds all files including in `dist/app/*.*`

Comment: Should work if you specify the complete path of the file to ignore- see update

Comment: It doesn't delete the folders. It only deletes the files inside.